# Get user response

Tags: moodle

Please, help me.

I'm creating a new question type (modifying gapselect question). I have some input forms in my question renderer (see screenshot below). In get_expected_data() I have:

```
$vars = array();
foreach ($this->places as $place => $notused) {
$vars[$this->field($place)] = PARAM_TEXT;
}
return $vars;
```

But it takes only numbers.

Are there ideas, what's wrong?

[numbers entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Aw8.png)

[letters entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uuLt.png)

HTML code of inputs:

```
$inputattributes = array(
'type' => 'text',
'name' => $inputname,
'value' => $currentanswer,
'id'     => $this->box_id($qa, 'p' . $place),
'size' => 30,
'class' => 'form-control',
);
$input = html_writer::empty_tag('input', $inputattributes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that the type is set to `text` and not to `number` for all the inputs

e.g.

```
// wrong
$mform->addElement('number', 'email', get_string('email'));
// correct
$mform->addElement('text', 'email', get_string('email'));
```

Alternatively check there are no rules associated with the element to enforce numeric input.

```
$mform->addRule('email', get_string('email'), 'numeric', ....
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added to my question, how my inputs look.

Comment: Any ideas for now?